# Graphic algorithm Unions, intersect, subtract

Tags: graphics

I need a good source for reading up on how to create a algorithm to take two polylines (a path comprised of many lines) and performing a union, subtraction, or intersection between them. This is tied to a custom API so I need to understand the underlying algorithm.

Plus any sources in a VB dialect would be doubly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [catalogue](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/intersection-detection.shtml) of implementations of intersection algorithms from the [Stony Brook Algorithm Repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith) might be useful. The repository is managed by Steven Skiena, 
author of a very well respected book on algorithms: [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693).

That's his own Amazon exec link by the way :)

Comment: That looks like it will do the trick and just a important I know what the algorithm is called and found more stuff on google, thanks.

Comment: Knowing the name of the algorithm is half the battle - maybe more.

Answer (score 5):

Several routines for you here. Hope you find them useful :-)

```
// routine to calculate the square of either the shortest distance or largest distance
// from the CPoint to the intersection point of a ray fired at an angle flAngle 
// radians at an array of line segments
// this routine returns TRUE if an intersection has been found in which case flD
// is valid and holds the square of the distance.
// and returns FALSE if no valid intersection was found
// If an intersection was found, then intersectionPoint is set to the point found
bool CalcIntersection(const CPoint &cPoint, 
                      const float flAngle,
                      const int nVertexTotal,
                      const CPoint *pVertexList,
                      const BOOL bMin,
                      float &flD,
                      CPoint &intersectionPoint)

{
    float d, dsx, dsy, dx, dy, lambda, mu, px, py;
    int p0x, p0y, p1x, p1y;

    // get source position 
    const float flSx = (float)cPoint.x;
    const float flSy = -(float)cPoint.y;

    // calc trig functions
    const float flTan = tanf(flAngle);
    const float flSin = sinf(flAngle);
    const float flCos = cosf(flAngle);
    const bool bUseSin = fabsf(flSin) > fabsf(flCos);

    // initialise distance
    flD = (bMin ? FLT_MAX : 0.0f);

    // for each line segment in protective feature
    for(int i = 0; i < nVertexTotal; i++) 
    {
        // get coordinates of line (negate the y value so the y-axis is upwards)
        p0x = pVertexList[i].x;
        p0y = -pVertexList[i].y;
        p1x = pVertexList[i + 1].x;
        p1y = -pVertexList[i + 1].y;

        // calc. deltas
        dsx = (float)(cPoint.x - p0x);
        dsy = (float)(-cPoint.y - p0y);
        dx = (float)(p1x - p0x);
        dy = (float)(p1y - p0y);

        // calc. denominator
        d = dy * flTan - dx;

        // if line & ray are parallel
        if(fabsf(d) < 1.0e-7f)
            continue;

        // calc. intersection point parameter
        lambda = (dsy * flTan - dsx) / d;

        // if intersection is not valid
        if((lambda <= 0.0f) || (lambda > 1.0f))
            continue;

        // if sine is bigger than cosine
        if(bUseSin){
            mu = ((float)p0x + lambda * dx - flSx) / flSin;
        } else {
            mu = ((float)p0y + lambda * dy - flSy) / flCos;
        }

        // if intersection is valid
        if(mu >= 0.0f){

            // calc. intersection point
            px = (float)p0x + lambda * dx;
            py = (float)p0y + lambda * dy;

            // calc. distance between intersection point & source point
            dx = px - flSx;
            dy = py - flSy;
            d = dx * dx + dy * dy;

            // compare with relevant value
            if(bMin){
                if(d < flD)
                {
                    flD = d;
                    intersectionPoint.x = RoundValue(px);
                    intersectionPoint.y = -RoundValue(py);
                }
            } else {
                if(d > flD)
                {
                    flD = d;
                    intersectionPoint.x = RoundValue(px);
                    intersectionPoint.y = -RoundValue(py);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // return 
    return(bMin ? (flD != FLT_MAX) : (flD != 0.0f));
}

// Routine to calculate the square of the distance from the CPoint to the
// intersection point of a ray fired at an angle flAngle radians at a line.
// This routine returns TRUE if an intersection has been found in which case flD
// is valid and holds the square of the distance.
// Returns FALSE if no valid intersection was found.
// If an intersection was found, then intersectionPoint is set to the point found.
bool CalcIntersection(const CPoint &cPoint, 
                      const float flAngle,
                      const CPoint &PointA,
                      const CPoint &PointB,
                      const bool bExtendLine,
                      float &flD,
                      CPoint &intersectionPoint)
{
    // get source position 
    const float flSx = (float)cPoint.x;
    const float flSy = -(float)cPoint.y;

    // calc trig functions
    float flTan = tanf(flAngle);
    float flSin = sinf(flAngle);
    float flCos = cosf(flAngle);
    const bool bUseSin = fabsf(flSin) > fabsf(flCos);

    // get coordinates of line (negate the y value so the y-axis is upwards)
    const int p0x = PointA.x;
    const int p0y = -PointA.y;
    const int p1x = PointB.x;
    const int p1y = -PointB.y;

    // calc. deltas
    const float dsx = (float)(cPoint.x - p0x);
    const float dsy = (float)(-cPoint.y - p0y);
    float dx = (float)(p1x - p0x);
    float dy = (float)(p1y - p0y);

    // Calc. denominator
    const float d = dy * flTan - dx;

    // If line & ray are parallel
    if(fabsf(d) < 1.0e-7f)
        return false;

    // calc. intersection point parameter
    const float lambda = (dsy * flTan - dsx) / d;

    // If extending line to meet point, don't check for ray missing line
    if(!bExtendLine)
    {
        // If intersection is not valid
        if((lambda <= 0.0f) || (lambda > 1.0f))
            return false;   // Ray missed line
    }

    // If sine is bigger than cosine
    float mu;
    if(bUseSin){
        mu = ((float)p0x + lambda * dx - flSx) / flSin;
    } else {
        mu = ((float)p0y + lambda * dy - flSy) / flCos;
    }

    // if intersection is valid
    if(mu >= 0.0f)
    {
        // calc. intersection point
        const float px = (float)p0x + lambda * dx;
        const float py = (float)p0y + lambda * dy;

        // calc. distance between intersection point & source point
        dx = px - flSx;
        dy = py - flSy;
        flD = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);

        intersectionPoint.x = RoundValue(px);
        intersectionPoint.y = -RoundValue(py);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Fillet (with a radius of 0) two lines. From point source fired at angle (radians) to line Line1A, Line1B.
// Modifies line end point Line1B. If the ray does not intersect line, then it is rotates every 90 degrees
// and tried again until fillet is complete.
void Fillet(const CPoint &source, const float fThetaRadians, const CPoint &Line1A, CPoint &Line1B)
{
    if(Line1A == Line1B)
        return; // No line

    float dist;

    if(CalcIntersection(source, fThetaRadians, Line1A, Line1B, true, dist, Line1B))
        return;
    if(CalcIntersection(source, CalcBaseFloat(TWO_PI, fThetaRadians + PI * 0.5f), Line1A, Line1B, true, dist, Line1B))
        return;
    if(CalcIntersection(source, CalcBaseFloat(TWO_PI, fThetaRadians + PI), Line1A, Line1B, true, dist, Line1B))
        return;
    if(!CalcIntersection(source, CalcBaseFloat(TWO_PI, fThetaRadians + PI * 1.5f), Line1A, Line1B, true, dist, Line1B))
        ASSERT(FALSE);  // Could not find intersection?
}

// routine to determine if an array of line segments cross gridSquare
// x and y give the float coordinates of the corners
BOOL CrossGridSquare(int nV, const CPoint *pV, 
                     const CRect &extent, const CRect  &gridSquare)
{
    // test extents
    if( (extent.right   < gridSquare.left) ||
        (extent.left    > gridSquare.right) ||  
        (extent.top     > gridSquare.bottom) ||
        (extent.bottom  < gridSquare.top))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    float a, b, c, dx, dy, s, x[4], y[4];
    int max_x, max_y, min_x, min_y, p0x, p0y, p1x, p1y, sign, sign_old;

    // construct array of vertices for grid square
    x[0] = (float)gridSquare.left;
    y[0] = (float)gridSquare.top;
    x[1] = (float)(gridSquare.right);
    y[1] = y[0];
    x[2] = x[1];
    y[2] = (float)(gridSquare.bottom);
    x[3] = x[0];
    y[3] = y[2];

    // for each line segment
    for(int i = 0; i < nV; i++) 
    {
        // get end-points
        p0x = pV[i].x;
        p0y = pV[i].y;
        p1x = pV[i + 1].x;
        p1y = pV[i + 1].y;

        // determine line extent
        if(p0x > p1x){
            min_x = p1x;
            max_x = p0x;
        } else {
            min_x = p0x;
            max_x = p1x;
        }

        if(p0y > p1y){
            min_y = p1y;
            max_y = p0y;
        } else {
            min_y = p0y;
            max_y = p1y;
        }

        // test to see if grid square is outside of line segment extent
        if( (max_x < gridSquare.left)  ||
            (min_x > gridSquare.right) ||  
            (max_y < gridSquare.top)   ||
            (min_y > gridSquare.bottom))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // calc. line equation
        dx = (float)(p1x - p0x);
        dy = (float)(p1y - p0y);
        a = dy;
        b = -dx;
        c = -dy * (float)p0x + dx * (float)p0y;

        // evaluate line eqn. at first grid square vertex
        s = a * x[0] + b * y[0] + c;
        if(s < 0.0f){
            sign_old = -1;
        } else if(s > 1.0f){
            sign_old = 1;
        } else {
            sign_old = 0;
        }

        // evaluate line eqn. at other grid square vertices
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) 
        {
            s = a * x[j] + b * y[j] + c;
            if(s < 0.0f){
                sign = -1;
            } else if(s > 1.0f){
                sign = 1;
            } else {
                sign = 0;
            }

            // if there has been a chnage in sign
            if(sign != sign_old)
                return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

// calculate the square of the shortest distance from point s
// and the line segment between p0 and p1
// t is the point on the line from which the minimum distance
// is measured
float CalcShortestDistanceSqr(const CPoint &s,
                              const CPoint &p0,
                              const CPoint &p1,
                              CPoint &t)
{
    // if point is at a vertex
    if((s == p0) || (s == p1))
        return(0.0F);

    // calc. deltas
    int dx = p1.x - p0.x;
    int dy = p1.y - p0.y;
    int dsx = s.x - p0.x;
    int dsy = s.y - p0.y;

    // if both deltas are zero 
    if((dx == 0) && (dy == 0))
    {
        // shortest distance is distance is to either vertex
        float l = (float)(dsx * dsx + dsy * dsy);
        t = p0;
        return(l);
    }

    // calc. point, p, on line that is closest to sourcePosition
    // p = p0 + l * (p1 - p0)
    float l = (float)(dsx * dx + dsy * dy) / (float)(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    // if intersection is beyond p0
    if(l <= 0.0F){

        // shortest distance is to p0
        l = (float)(dsx * dsx + dsy * dsy);
        t = p0;

    // else if intersection is beyond p1
    } else if(l >= 1.0F){

        // shortest distance is to p1
        dsx = s.x - p1.x;
        dsy = s.y - p1.y;
        l = (float)(dsx * dsx + dsy * dsy);
        t = p1;

    // if intersection is between line end points
    } else {
        // calc. perpendicular distance
        float ldx = (float)dsx - l * (float)dx;
        float ldy = (float)dsy - l * (float)dy;
        t.x = p0.x + RoundValue(l * (float)dx);
        t.y = p0.y + RoundValue(l * (float)dy);
        l = ldx * ldx + ldy * ldy;
    }

    return(l);
}

// Calculates the bounding rectangle around a set of points
// Returns TRUE if the rectangle is not empty (has area), FALSE otherwise
// Opposite of CreateRectPoints()
BOOL CalcBoundingRectangle(const CPoint *pVertexList, const int nVertexTotal, CRect &rect)
{
    rect.SetRectEmpty();
    if(nVertexTotal < 2)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);  // Must have at least 2 points
        return FALSE;
    }

    // First point, set rectangle (no area at this point)
    rect.left = rect.right = pVertexList[0].x;
    rect.top = rect.bottom = pVertexList[0].y;

    // Increst rectangle by looking at other points
    for(int n = 1; n < nVertexTotal; n++)
    {
        if(rect.left > pVertexList[n].x)    // Take minimum
            rect.left = pVertexList[n].x;

        if(rect.right < pVertexList[n].x)   // Take maximum
            rect.right = pVertexList[n].x;

        if(rect.top > pVertexList[n].y)     // Take minimum
            rect.top = pVertexList[n].y;

        if(rect.bottom < pVertexList[n].y)  // Take maximum
            rect.bottom = pVertexList[n].y;
    }

    rect.NormalizeRect();   // Normalise rectangle
    return !(rect.IsRectEmpty());
}
```